# Oracle Database 'lsnrctl start': "Failed to start listener service, error 1069: The service did not start due to a logon failure."

Tags: windows, oracle, permissions

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>lsnrctl start

LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on 08-APR-2022 08:41:35

Copyright (c) 1991, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Starting tnslsnr: please wait...

Failed to start listener service, error 1069: The service did not start due to a logon failure.

TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
 TNS-00530: Protocol adapter error


C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

There is an Oracle Home User (see https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/ntdbi/creating-oracle-home-user.html), which I have named OracleDBUser.

However, I log in to Windows as an ordinary user (afeldstein01). I open the Command Window as administrator and get the above result.

Using the Event Viewer, I find more information. Event 4625:

```
An account failed to log on.

Subject:
    Security ID:        SYSTEM
    Account Name:       HH00DL89040448$
    Account Domain:     TXHHSC
    Logon ID:       0x3E7

Logon Type:         5

Account For Which Logon Failed:
    Security ID:        NULL SID
    Account Name:       OracleDBUser
    Account Domain:     HH00DL89040448

Failure Information:
    Failure Reason:     The user has not been granted the requested logon type at this machine.
    Status:         0xC000015B
    Sub Status:     0x0

Process Information:
    Caller Process ID:  0x47c
    Caller Process Name:    C:\Windows\System32\services.exe

Network Information:
    Workstation Name:   HH00DL89040448
    Source Network Address: -
    Source Port:        -

Detailed Authentication Information:
    Logon Process:      Advapi  
    Authentication Package: Negotiate
    Transited Services: -
    Package Name (NTLM only):   -
    Key Length:     0

This event is generated when a logon request fails. It is generated on the computer where access was attempted.

The Subject fields indicate the account on the local system which requested the logon. This is most commonly a service such as the Server service, or a local process such as Winlogon.exe or Services.exe.

The Logon Type field indicates the kind of logon that was requested. The most common types are 2 (interactive) and 3 (network).

The Process Information fields indicate which account and process on the system requested the logon.

The Network Information fields indicate where a remote logon request originated. Workstation name is not always available and may be left blank in some cases.

The authentication information fields provide detailed information about this specific logon request.
    - Transited services indicate which intermediate services have participated in this logon request.
    - Package name indicates which sub-protocol was used among the NTLM protocols.
    - Key length indicates the length of the generated session key. This will be 0 if no session key was requested.
```

Comment: The docs say: "If you want to create a new user during installation, then it can only be a Windows Local User. It cannot be a Windows Domain User, an MSA, or a gMSA. The new user that is created is denied interactive logon privileges to the Windows computer."  

so the fact that you could logon at that user suggests you perhaps have not configured things correctly?

Comment: Thank you @ConnorMcDonald. I had not noticed the paragraph you quoted. OracleDBUser was created by the Oracle Database installer as a Windows Local User, not a Windows Domain User and not a managed service account. It is clear to me now that I am not to log on to that account interactively. Error Code 0xC000006A means "Account logon with misspelled or bad password." I had changed the OracleDBUser password after Oracle Database installation. I have now changed it back. I'm updating my question because the result is now slightly different. I'm not getting 0xC000006A anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Unwisely, while trying to bring up the database, I decided to change the password of the Oracle Home User. (I should have stayed focused on bringing up the database.) I never told Oracle Database about the password change. Like I said in my 2022-04-13 comment, I changed the password back to its original as a Windows password change.

Today, I found that, in the properties of OracleOraDB19Home1TNSListener, on the Log On tab, changing the password back to its original cleared the "The user has not been granted the requested logon type at this machine" error.